# Delete subsequent rows after row meets criteria

Tags: r

how do I delete subsequent rows after a certain row meets a criteria? For example, with a smaller test data set:

```
##test##
testdata<-cbind(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8), (c("05/01/2001","01/04/2001", "02/02/2002",     "02/03/2003")))
colnames(testdata)<-c("x", "y", "DOD")
testdata<-as.data.frame(testdata)
testdata$DOD<-as.Date(testdata$DOD, "%m/%d/%Y")
testtemp<-cbind(c(20,30,40), (c("01/01/2001","01/02/2001", "02/02/2002")))
colnames(testtemp)<-c("TMAX", "DATE")
```

Then I create a bigger dataset:

```
##########LOOP TO GENERATE DATA##########
collapse<-function(data,temp) 
{
newdata<-data[rep(1:nrow(data),each=nrow(temp)),]
newdata$status = 0
newdata<-cbind(newdata, temp)
newdata$status<-ifelse(newdata$DOD == newdata$DATE, 1, 0)
return(newdata)
}
```

Which returns something like this:

```
    x y DOD        status TMAX DATE
1   1 5 2001-05-01      0   20 2001-01-01
1.1 1 5 2001-05-01      0   30 2001-01-02
1.2 1 5 2001-05-01      0   40 2002-02-02
2   2 6 2001-01-04      0   20 2001-01-01
2.1 2 6 2001-01-04      0   30 2001-01-02
2.2 2 6 2001-01-04      0   40 2002-02-02
3   3 7 2002-02-02      0   20 2001-01-01
3.1 3 7 2002-02-02      0   30 2001-01-02
3.2 3 7 2002-02-02      1   40 2002-02-02
4   4 8 2003-02-03      0   20 2001-01-01
4.1 4 8 2003-02-03      0   30 2001-01-02
4.2 4 8 2003-02-03      0   40 2002-02-02
```

I would like to delete all rows after status=1, so the last three rows in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `which` and subsetting to find the first row which meets your condition and subset it if there is a matching condition otherwise, do nothing...

```
idx <- which( newdata$DOD == newdata$DATE ) 
if( length( idx ) > 0L ) newdata <- newdata[ seq_len( idx ) , ]
```