# Deleting rows after previous row meets a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have trawled through all the other examples of this question including but not limited to - [R: Removing All Rows After Condition Is Met](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75180727/19389199) and [Delete subsequent rows after row meets criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18083365/19389199) - and I can't make any of the example codes work for my data.

I want to remove all rows after any row (grouped by ID) is >= 140.
If no rows meet the condition, they all remain.

Example data:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
sBP <- c(130, 139, 140, 141, 120, 122, 123, 140, 126, 127, 130)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, sBP)
```

[image: DF1]

This is what I would like the data to look like:

[image: DF2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to adjust your example. For this, `DF1[DF1$sBP < 140L, ]` is all you need. I see no dependence on `ID`.

Comment: Agreed with @Friede, this is just using dplyr: `library(dplyr); DF1 %>% filter(sBP < 140)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, please try

```r
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, sBP) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new=ifelse(sBP>=140,1,NA)) %>% 
  fill(new) %>% filter(is.na(new)) %>% 
  select(-new)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  # A tibble: 5 × 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID   sBP
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   130
2     1   139
3     2   120
4     2   122
5     2   123
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` solution from the first link you shared may throw a warning depending on your real data, but does work:

```r
library(dplyr)


DF1 %>%
  filter(row_number() < min(which(sBP >= 140)), .by = ID)
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `filter()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `row_number() < min(which(sBP >= 140))`.
#> ℹ In group 2: `ID = 2`.
#> Caused by warning in `min()`:
#> ! no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#>   ID sBP
#> 1  1 130
#> 2  1 139
#> 3  2 120
#> 4  2 122
#> 5  2 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Here´s a solution with `purrr`:

```
libray(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_df(
  unique(ID), 
  \(x) tibble(
    id = x, 
    sbp = head_while(sBP[ID == x], \(y) y < 140)))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
     id   sbp
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   130
2     1   139
3     2   120
4     2   122
5     2   123
```