# Remove rows in two columns based on separate conditions in each column

Tags: r, dplyr

I asked a similar simpler question yesterday - which received a dplyr answer - [Deleting rows after previous row meets a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455233/19389199)

I have a slightly more complex query - if I have two columns (sBP and dBP), and I want to remove all rows after a condition is met in sBP, or a different condition is met in dBP.

So, if a row in sBP is >= 140, then all the rows in sBP from that point on, and all the corresponding rows in dBP from that point on, should be removed. If dBP reaches >= 90 first, then all the rows following that should be removed, concurrently removing all corresponding rows in sBP. (Grouped per ID).

If no rows in either column meet either condition - all rows remain.

Here is an example of my data:

```
Id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
sBP <- c(130,130,140,131, 140, 120, 121, 121, 120, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 120, 140, 120)
dBP <- c(89,87,88,70, 89, 90, 70, 70, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 90, 80, 70, 90, 80, 60 )
DF1 <- data.frame(Id, sBP, dBP)
```

[image: DF1]

And this is what I would like the result to be:
[image: DF2]

I hope this makes sense - any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cumsum()` or `dplyr::cumany()` (thanks to @r2evans for the reminder) you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

DF1 |>
  filter(!cumsum(sBP >= 140) & !cumsum(dBP >= 90), .by = Id)
#>   Id sBP dBP
#> 1  1 130  89
#> 2  1 130  87
#> 3  3 130  72
#> 4  3 130  73
#> 5  3 130  74
#> 6  3 130  76
#> 7  4 130  70
```

or

```r
DF1 |>
  filter(!cumany(sBP >= 140) & !cumany(dBP >= 90), .by = Id)
#>   Id sBP dBP
#> 1  1 130  89
#> 2  1 130  87
#> 3  3 130  72
#> 4  3 130  73
#> 5  3 130  74
#> 6  3 130  76
#> 7  4 130  70
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modified [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77455442/20002111) from yesterday:

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 |>
  filter(row_number() < min(which(sBP >= 140L | dBP >= 90L)), .by = Id)
```

gives

```
  Id sBP dBP
1  1 130  89
2  1 130  87
3  3 130  72
4  3 130  73
5  3 130  74
6  3 130  76
7  4 130  70
```