# Removing rows from a dataframe after a condition has been met multiple times in multiple columns using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I asked a similar question about a condition being met in either row ([Remove rows in two columns based on separate conditions in each column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77459364/19389199)): I am now looking for a slight variation on this question:

I have a dataframe in R containing blood pressure readings (SystolicBP and DiastolicBP) identified by ID. I want to filter out rows where either the SystolicBP reaches 140 or higher or the DiastolicBP reaches 90 or higher.
However, I want to remove rows only after either of these conditions has been met **twice or more** for the same ID. The condition could be met once in one column and then the second time in the other column. I would like to remove the second instance of either ≥140 (in SystolicBP) and/or ≥90 (in DiastolicBP), and any following rows per ID.

Example data:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
SystolicBP <- c(140, 139, 142, 139, 120, 111,113,118,139,120,142,120,118,110)
DiastolicBP <- c(87, 70, 71, 70, 70, 72, 90, 84, 97, 80, 73, 74, 90, 73)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, SystolicBP, DiastolicBP)
```

[image: DF1]

This is what I would like the data to look like:
[image: DF2]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 

DF1 %>% 
  filter(cumsum(SystolicBP >= 140 | DiastolicBP >= 90) < 2, .by = ID)

# A tibble: 9 × 3
     ID SystolicBP DiastolicBP
  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1        140          87
2     1        139          70
3     2        120          70
4     2        111          72
5     2        113          90
6     2        118          84
7     3        120          80
8     3        142          73
9     3        120          74
```